# Error 1064 in SQL statement

Tags: mysql

I have tried to run a SQL command but I am receiving this error:
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')`

The SQL statement is

```
SELECT                                        * , 
     Match(product.title) against (query) + match(product.description) against (query1) +match(product.keyword) against (query2)+match(product.url) against (query2) + (average(review.rating)/100*count(productid))+(100/price)+(site.domainauthority/25)+(10- 
     CASE 
              WHEN lcase(seller.city) = lcase(city) THEN TRUNCATE(( 6371 * acos( cos( radians( 23 ) ) * cos( radians( seller.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( seller.longitude ) - radians(24) ) + sin( radians( 24 ) ) * sin( radians( seller.latitude ) ) ) ),1))
ELSE + 0 
END AS score 
FROM     product, 
         productimages, 
         review, 
         seller, 
         site 
WHERE    distance < 10 
AND      productimage.id=product.id 
AND      product.sellerid =seller.id 
AND      product.siteid-site.id 
AND      productmeta.id = product.id 
AND      review.productid = product.id 
AND      (( 
                       seller.deliverabletype = "international") 
     OR       ( 
                       seller.deliverabletype = "country" 
              AND      seller.country = 'country') 
     OR       ( 
                       seller.deliverabletype = "state" 
              AND      seller.country = 'country') 
     OR 
     OR       ( 
                       seller.deliverabletype = "city" 
              AND      seller.country = 'city')) 
GROUP BY product.id mysql sql-server
```

Comment: How about formatting your SQL first?

Answer (score 0):

The query was not well formed. One of the closing parenthesis should be at the end.

try this.
    TRUNCATE(
                    ( 6371 * acos( 
                                    cos( radians( 23 ) ) * cos( radians( seller.latitude ) ) * 
                                    cos( radians( seller.longitude ) - radians(24) ) + 
                                    sin( radians( 24 ) ) * sin( radians( seller.latitude ) )
                                ) 
                    ),1)

ELSE + 0 
END) AS score

Comment: you should explain how this fixes OP's mistake (what OP's mistake was)